# MQQueue get method takes too long from remote server

Tags: java, performance, ibm-mq

Im trying to read message (approx 1Mb size) from remote queue. Method **queue.get(theMessage, gmo)** takes about 3-6 seconds to complete. Is there any options (like buffer size) to improve performance?

```
qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
            int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE;

            MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qQueue, openOptions);

            MQMessage theMessage = new MQMessage();

            //theMessage.messageFlags = CMQC.MQMF_SEGMENTATION_ALLOWED;
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER | CMQC.MQGMO_ALL_SEGMENTS_AVAILABLE | CMQC.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG | CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT | CMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
            gmo.matchOptions = CMQC.MQMO_NONE;
            gmo.waitInterval = 5000;
            queue.get(theMessage, gmo);
```

Comment: Are the messages persistent?

Comment: Yes. Messages persistent. Ping to remote server about 100ms. Maybe i need to rewrite my application with multiple threads?

Comment: What version and fixpack level of the MQ server and client are you using?

Comment: Yiu might want to try configuring message compression.

Comment: Im using 7.0.1 java libraries with Websphere MQ server  **7.5.0-WS-MQ-LinuxX64-FP0007**.  I can not change the settings of a remote MQ server.

Comment: Are there definitely messages waiting to be retrieved? You have a wait time of 5 seconds and mention a delay of around 5 seconds too.

Comment: The Compression setting would be on the SVRCONN channel you connect to and in your client side: See "[Channel compression in WebSphere MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031090_.htm)" and "[Data compression (COMPMSG)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q081840_.htm)".

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to give advice without concrete data

the MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER can affect performence significntly - I would test if removing it improves perfomence

MQGMO_ALL_SEGMENTS_AVAILABLE appears irrelevant as MQMF_SEGMENTATION_ALLOWED is commented out - but if it's used it can also affect perfomence

try also running trace on the server and \ or client side to get more insight on what takes so long

Comment: When applciation run same machine with Websphere MQ there is no performance issues. And time to get message not affecct how many messages in the queue 3000 or 1

Answer (score 0):

> Ping to remote server about 100ms. Maybe i need to rewrite my
>   application with multiple threads?

Well, that would explain a lot.   Pinging a server should take less than 5ms and approach 1ms.  If it takes 100ms, then your network is SLOW, really SLOW.

No amount of programming, except for compression, will solve your issue.  And even then compression is no magic bullet.

Go to your network people and ask them what is the network speed between the 2 servers.  If they say it is less than 1Gb/s then point out that it is the 21st century and your application requires a minimum of 1Gb/s.

Comment: Hi Roger, distance plays a big part in ms response time.  You can't speed up the speed of light.  Try pinging from the AMRS to EMEA or ASIA and see how much your ms response time is, it will be much greater than 1ms to 5ms even if the speed of the link is 10 Gb/s.

Comment: Sure, i have 1Gb channel on my server located in Russia. MQ server located in US. I try to measure speed between server with FTP server. It takes about 3-5Mib on big files.

Comment: @JoshMc well I was thinking more like 250 miles not 5000 miles.

Comment: @loljeene I don't know what you mean by "It takes about 3-5Mib on big files". Since you are doing an MQGET, try downloading several 10MB files and time how long it takes then calculate the speed of that particular network link.

Comment: @Roger Actual connection speed on 10Mb files like 10-30Mbps. It looks like reading from InputStream in java with small buffer size when working with mq